# how to solve "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to type 'System.IConvertible".error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I get an error when I try to equalize the first int value to an object of type short by splitting the string expression into two using regex match.

My code

```
 var splitedResolution = sub.ResolutionValue.Split('*');
 var resolutionwidht = Regex.Match(splitedResolution[0], @"\b\d+\.?\d?\b");   
 resolutionReportsub.Width =Convert.ToInt16(resolutionwidht);
```

Comment: simply use `resolutionWidth.Value`.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16(resolutionwidht.Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Match`-method returns a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=net-6.0)-object. This object also has a `Success`-property to determine if the string matched your pattern.

In order to get the actually matched string use `theMatchObject.Value`:

```
var splitedResolution = sub.ResolutionValue.Split('*');
var resolutionwidht = Regex.Match(splitedResolution[0], @"\b\d+\.?\d?\b");   
resolutionReportsub.Width =Convert.ToInt16(resolutionwidht.Value);
```